# Change maxZoom option in runtime to ol.View in Openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Im trying to change the maxZoom option once a functionality of the map is activated. So it has to be during runtime so it can be rolled back to the original maxZoom.

Creating the ol.View you configure this parameters like this:

```
new ol.View({
                ...
                zoom: 10,
                maxZoom: 17,
                minZoom: 10,
});
```

however, the api only allows to change zoom with [setZoom()](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.1/apidoc/ol.View.html#setZoom)

Comment: Same here; I've tried doing something like mylayer.set("maxZoom", max), but it doesn't do anything. In my case I'm trying to change the max zoom if the browser is offline, as only the first 3 levels are cached offline.

Comment: Check our the Answer below @JoseGómez

Comment: And I just realised that there is a difference between setting the max zoom on a view than setting it on a layer. If set on a layer, the view should allow you to go deeper, but keeping the same imagery.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution someone posted:

You can accomplish this by changing the view of the map completely:

```
map.setView(new ol.View({
  zoom: 10,
  maxZoom: 17,
  minZoom: 10,
}));
```

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kalifa17/e420fye5/) to test the solution

Comment: Thanks, that works great. Based on this one I have created an alternate solution (http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/222597/37469) that might be better suited in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

kalifa17's solution works beautifully and is very simple; perfect for most cases.

In case of more complex views, a new view could be created reusing the properties of the old one:

```
var properties = map.getView().getProperties();
properties["maxZoom"] = 5;
map.setView(new ol.View(properties));
```

Or if you want to ensure the current view is within the updated maximum (as for some reason the solution above doesn't enforce this):

```
var zoom = map.getView().getZoom();
var properties = map.getView().getProperties();
properties["maxZoom"] = 5;
map.setView(new ol.View(properties));
if (zoom > 5) {
    this.map.getView().setZoom(5);
}
```